# Nginx status is failed so how to make nginx up and running

Tags: nginx

I have project developed in Node + react combination. We have deployed it on aws. But from last some days site stopped working. I have checked domain but i didnt find any issue with domain. Actully when I checked with terminal I noticed that I didnt receive any request from client side when I hit the website from browser.

So I checked with nginx status but its showing me failed. I have attached image which shows nginx status. Can anyone tell me how I can make nginx up and running again. I am completely new to handling server things. So I dont have that much knowledge about it. Thanks in advance
[image]
[image]

Comment: Run `journalctl -xe` and look for the exact nginx error. Most probably a typo in your config file.

Comment: @IVO GELOV I have added another image. Can you get the type of error from it ?

Comment: run `nginx -t` to see what it thinks about your config

Comment: @TheFool  it saying "nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed"

Comment: from second image its saying ssl error, but its cut off, how does the line end?

Comment: Maybe your SSL private key is password protected - https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_password_file